# Turning an equation into a function in a module

Tags: function-construction, scoping

I have defined a function like this:

```
f[q_] := Module[{g},
    g[x_] := Evaluate[q];
    ...
]
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
f[2+4x+6x^2]
```

It's not working, because when I look at the definition of g in f, it looks like this:

```
f$23750[x$_]:=2+4 x+6 x^2
```

The "$" makes it appear like it's trying to treat x as local to the module, but I need to to retain it as exactly x so I can pass in an equation in x.  I don't want to pass a lambda as this is more cumbersome and hard to read.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into the automatic renaming of variables that Mathematica does when there are variable naming conflicts. One workaround is to use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive)/[`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate) as follows:

```
f[q_] := Module[{g},
    Activate[Inactive[SetDelayed][g[x_],Evaluate[q]]];
    DownValues[g]
]
```

Then:

```
f[2 + 4 x + 6 x^2]
```

> {HoldPattern[g$411457[x_]] :> 2 + 4 x + 6 x^2}

shows that the variable renaming has been avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
f[q_]:= Module[{g},
  g[x_]:= Evaluate[q];
  g[q]]
```

Your original code does not evaluate your function `g[]`.

Comment: It does evaluate it later (in the "..." part, which I was omitting for brevity).  And when I pass an integer to g, it returns my equation, not the result of substituting the integer into the equation.  When I passed g to "Definition" it appeared to show me that it wasn't using "x" but was instead changing it to "x$".

Comment: Incidentally, if I change the equation I pass to substitute "x" with "x$" it works, but this seems like a workaround in misunderstanding of the correct way to define g.

Comment: @Michael - I suggest that you edit your question and supply the minimum workable code that demonstrates the problem.